# Output of JAVA program [polymorphism, method overriding]

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I am currently learning the JAVA programming language. In my lecturer's notes I found the following code snippet:

```
class Base{
   void g(){
     System.out.print("g-Base ");
   }
   void f(){
     System.out.print("f-Base ");
     g();
   }
}
class Derived extends Base{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Base b = new Derived();  b.f();
   }
   void g() {
      System.out.print("g-Derived ");
   }
   void f() {
      System.out.print("f-Derived "); super.f();
   }
}
```

The question is: what is the output of this program. I compiled and ran it and got: f-Derived f-Base g-Derived
I understand the f-Derived and f-Base parts, but why did it print "g-Derived" in the last step, I thought it should have been "g-Base".

Comment: Just like ```Base b = new Derived(); b.g();``` Would print ```g-Derived```.

Comment: Yes, but if the code jumps to super.f() and calls g() from there, shouldn't it continue calling the g() from super?

Comment: No, it's a dynamic invocation (happens at runtime) on ```this``` i.e. ```this.g()```. ```this``` has the dynamic type of ```Derived```, so ```Derived::g``` is called.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. I think I got it, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler knows the following rules:

> If a method is called without `super` keyword call the `Derived`
>   version but if a method is called with `super` keyword call the `Base`
>   version.

So when `super.f()` is called the `Base` version of `f()` is called but when `g()` is called within the `Base` version and since this invocation is without `super` keyword (with implicit `this` keyword where `this` refers to `Derived` object) the Compiler happily calls the `Derived` version and we get the output: `g-Derived`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let's track the sequence of execution:

1. `Derived#f` is called and prints `"f-Derived".
2. `Derived#f` then calls `super.f()`, which means `Base#f`.
3. `Base#f` prints `"f-Base"`.
4. `Base#f` then calls `g()`. Since `g()` is overriden in `Derived`, `Derived#g` is called.
5. `Derived#g` prints `"g-Derived"`.

Comment: But how does the compiler know, that when Base#f calls g(), it should use the overriden g() instead of the base one? I think I'm probably missing some small part of the logic. Thanks for the answer though :)